# Count of users in one group

Tags: opendj

Is it possible to get count of users in one group with opendj sdk?

e.g. my group has multi-values UniqueMember attribute, but is it possible that I get the count of the UniqueMember? because I don't want to list all the users, just to get the count.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no standard in LDAP to retrieve the number of values of an attribute of a given entry.

Comment: thanks, and what if the static group has many members，does opendj support range retrieve, just like AD does?

Comment: OpenDJ does not implement the Microsoft AD range retrieval option, because there is no standard document that specify the option and its behaviour, and also because the option violates the LDAP specifications (RFC 4512 does not allow the use of the equals sign in attribute options).